# Align x axis of one ChartArea with y axis of another?

Tags: .net, alignment, mschart, charts

I'm working with System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting (C#, VS 2008).

I have two `ChartArea`s, one containing a `SeriesChartType.Line` and the other containing a `SeriesChartType.RangeBar`.  Separatly the two charts plot what I want.  The horizontal axis in both is time, and I'd like to align them so that I can zoom them together, etc.

The horizontal axis of the `Line` chart is the x axis, but the horizontal axis of the `RangeBar` chart is the y axis.  When I set `AlignWithChartArea` of one chart with the name of the other, the linked axes are crossed (the horizontal (x) axis of the Line chart links with the *vertical* (x) axis of the RangeBar chart).

Is there an easy way to get the two horizontal axes to link, or am I asking too much?

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? http://betterdashboards.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/align-multiple-chart-areas/

Comment: Thanks for the link Dustin.  There are a bunch of blogs from there that I had no idea existed.  The post you reference doesn't address the issue I have, because it deals with two line charts.  These series both have the same orientation (x axis is horizontal).  One of mine has the y axis horizontal, and this is turning out to be a big headache.

Comment: I appreciate your response though (it's the first one I've gotten on four questions on the charting tools!)  (+1) Cheers!