# Under what circumstances would I want to handle ChartArea.AxisViewChanging instead of ChartArea.AxisViewChanged?

Tags: .net, events, data-visualization, mschart, charts

Continuing my code incantations with DataVisualization.Charting in the System.Windows.Forms namespace.

Still working to figure out how to tie two horizontal axes: one with a Point ChartArea and another with a RangeBar ChartArea.

As I scroll around on the axes of these graphs, I can handle ChartArea.AxisViewChanging or ChartArea.AxisViewChanged.  Both events provide a ViewEventArgs object as input, which contains fields like NewPosition, NewSize, NewSizeType, which I'd think would be the updated values for the axis view range, position, etc.

When would I want to handle AxisViewChanging vs. AxisViewChanged?  Are things "more finalized" when AxisViewChanged is called?  For what I'm trying to do ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862624/align-x-axis-of-one-chartarea-with-y-axis-of-another), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904427/how-do-i-get-the-data-in-a-point-charttype-and-a-rangebar-charttype-to-line-up-ex), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957157/how-to-do-aligned-scrolling-through-two-chart-areas-without-using-aligntochartare)) it may make a big difference when the object "takes" the new values provided in the ViewEventArgs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From books online (links included below):

[AxisViewChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.axisviewchanging.aspx)
Occurs when the axis scale view position or size is **about** to change.

[AxisViewChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.axisviewchanged.aspx)
Called when the axis scale view position or size is changed.

The first fires before anything has actually changed.